# css border-radius circle becomes ellipse with position: absolute

Tags: html, css, css-position, font-awesome

I am creating a circle around a font awesome icon. My problem is when I add `position: absolute` the circle became an ellipse.

The same happens if I was to set `display: block`

[image]

Here is an image of what I am trying to achieve -

[image]

```
<slide class="assessment-score">
  <div class="score-heading pass">
    <span id="score-salutation" class="light">CONRADULATIONS</span>
    <span id="score-message">YOU HAVE PASSED</span>
    <i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="score-results">
    <span id="score">You have scored 92%</span>
    <button>DOWNLOAD YOU CERTIFICATE</button>
    <a id="assessment-close"><i class="fa fa-times-circle-o"></i> CLOSE ASSESSMENT</a>
  </div>
</slide>
```

the css

```
slide.assessment-score .score-heading{
  height: 33%;
  background-color: #a8db66;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  color: #ffffff;
  position: relative;
}
slide.assessment-score .score-heading i{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  font-size: 6em;
  margin-bottom: -30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 1rem
  background-color: black;
}
```

Comment: you need to define the width and height with absolute positioning OR wrap it in a relative positioned div OR set the positioning to relative and use the top,left to position it

Comment: The problem isn't because you've set `position:absolute`. It's because you've set `right: 0` AND `left:0`. That tells it to occupy the full width.

Comment: the problem is the height width will change so I won't know the value

Comment: I have set `right: 0` and `left: 0` to centre it, is this wrong?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. You're right, but you also need `margin: 0 auto;`, and you need to define the width with this solution. You say that the width and height change, but maybe if you define `width: 1em`? That would be with respect to the `font-size` that you define on `i`.

Comment: changing `width: 1em` does make a circle but pushes it to the left

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To horizontally center an absolutely positioned `div` you don't use `left: 0` and `right: 0`. As you can see, that actually stretches it out by setting one end of the `div` to the left edge of the containing box, and the other end to the right edge.

To horizontally center an absolutely positioned `div` try this:

```
slide.assessment-score .score-heading i {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, 0);
}
```

For details about how this works see: [Element will not stay centered, especially when re-sizing screen](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36817249/3597276)

Comment: great thanks, your example and the comments left make sense as to why I had the problem